# Python 'in' operator search algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, search

I want to know what is the search algorithm used for implementing the python `in` operator. For example:

```
   if num in some_large_list:
      do_something(num)
```

I notice that it seems to be slow on large lists , what is the algorithmic complexity of the `in` operator ? How does it scale with size of the list. Can we implement something better?

(I have asked how the `in` operator has been implemented in python, what search algorithm it uses , and can we do something better than that for larger lists)

Comment: Do you mean the "in" operation as in the "check if contains operation"? Or do you mean the "for ... in ..." operation?

Comment: The larger your list the more values it has to iterate over so it makes sense that it  slows as your list grows

Comment: That is not an answer to my question and there is no such answer in the previous questions you mentioned in duplicates

Answer (score 0):

```
for num in some_large_list:
```

This basically iterates over the elements in the list one by one from starting till end. So, This time will obviously increase for longer lists.

---

What I think is increasing your running time is the operations you are performing inside the loop

```
do_something(num)
```